# No progress bar during installation

Tags: system-installation

I am currently installing Ubuntu onto my laptop as the Windows 8 OS has somehow disappeared from my HDD and I was prompted with `No bootable device` every time I started it up.

I went through everything as it came up on the screen and all went well. However, I am now at the stage were you can learn more about Ubuntu as it installs but there is no progress bar at the bottom.

I can scroll through the pages and it shows me all the features of Ubuntu; however it doesn't say how far the install is along? I am installing via USB and I have noticed that every now and then the led in my USB drive is flashing, but there is still no progress bar.

Is it best to just wait and see what happens? I'm really confused.

Comment: adam - if the "adam wright" you posted the comment as an answer, then click the contact us link at the bottom of the page and request that your two accounts are merged.  When you have done this you will be able to edit your question with any replies.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the bootable USB? I've used unetbootin in the past, but it doesn't seem to work as reliably now, and I had this very problem. I've had good success using

```
sudo dd if=~/source.iso of=/dev/destination_usb
```

'if'  is input file, 'of'  is output file.